# Yii2 - How to call ActiveRecord method given its name

Tags: php, yii2

I have a `string` variable that contains the *model*'s class name, and I want to call a method on said *model* using that variable, is that possible??

My code:

```php
foreach($tables as $tables)
{
    $table = ArrayHelper::getValue($tables, 'table_name');
    $model = \common\models\$table::findAll();
    var_dump($model);
}
```

A simpler version:

```php
$table = "DataAnalysis";
$model = \common\models\$table::findAll();
var_dump($model);
```

When I run that code, I get the following error:

> Exception 'ParseError' with message 'syntax error, unexpected '$table' (T_VARIABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)'

Is there anything I can do to call *model* given the string contained in the variable?

Comment: What do you mean by "call model with variable"? Do you mean you want to find all models where one of the properties matches the value in the variable? Like "find all models where name is "my-model-name"

Comment: @RaulSauco I have variable that contain model name, like this $table = "DataAnalysis"; , and I want to use that variable to call model like this, $model = \common\models\$table::findAll();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply do,

```
$model="\\common\\models\\DataAnalysis";
$model::findAll();
```

OR

```
$table="DataAnalysis"; 
$model="\\common\\models\\{$table}"; 
$model::findAll();
```

rather than `call_user_func()` thats too much code for a simple task

**Edit**

If you need to instantiate the class instead of static call, you can simply do

```
$table="DataAnalysis"; 
$model="\\common\\models\\{$table}"; 
new $model();
```

Comment: hi @Reborn, thank you, this is the simpler way, but today I also face another problem, I need to use the variable to initialize new model like this, $model = new "\\common\\models\\{$table}"();.. I try to use your solution but not working..

Comment: @biladina see my answer i have edited to add the info

Answer (score 1):

##### You can do it using `call_user_func()`.

```php
// If you have the name of the ActiveRecord class, like in you comment
$class = 'DataAnalysis';

/** @var ActiveQuery $query */
$query = call_user_func($class . '::find');

// Then use the query as you want
foreach($query->each() as $model) {
    // Do something with your model
}
```

If you are not sure if the value in the variable will always be correct, wrap it on a `try/catch`.

If what you have is the table name, and not the class name, you can try to convert with the [Yii inflector camelize method](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseinflector#camelize()-detail).

```php
use yii\helpers\Inflector;

$tableName = 'some_snake_case_name';
$className = Inflector::camelize($tableName);
/** @var ActiveQuery $query */
$query = call_user_func($className . '::find');

// If you want to filter results
$query->where(...);

// Then use the query as you want
foreach($query->each() as $model) {
    // Do something with your model
}
```

`call_user_function` [docs are here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php).

Comment: hi @RaulSauco, today I get another problem, I also need to use the variable to initialize new model like this, $model = new $className();.. I try to use your solution but not working.. should I open a new question or I can update my question above??

Comment: @biladina asking a new question is best, have a look at the [ask] section if in doubt.